# Graphical editor with only one important feature - crop

Tags: linux, graphics, image-editing

99% of my Gimp starts is a

- open the image
- do the restangular selection
- crop image to selection
- save

Gimp start slowly, ask 100 questions about "Am I sure" for each step, thats way i want some another soft.

May you recommend me simple editor (linux, gtk) for this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out pinta, it's similar to Paint in Windows but for linux.  Very small, fast and efficient.

[Project Homepage](http://pinta-project.com/)

Perhaps this isn't exactly what you are looking for, but many online photo hosts offer limited editing abilities at the push of a button.  Depending what you're doing with your photos you could upload them, crop them quickly, then either download them or submit them, or whatever you're doing.

Comment: Yeah, just tried. Looks nice. Small minus is mono deps, but no so important

Answer (score 2):

[ShowFoto](http://www.digikam.org/node/326) is my favourite solution for such tasks. easily open folder with images, use mouse to select an rectangular area and use context menu to crop the image. Then one-click to save. Very useful when you need to quickly crop bunch of images.

[image: Showfoto screenshot]

Comment: Yep, but + tons of kde stuff as dependencies.

Comment: Ok, not my problem with Kubuntu :-)

Answer (score 1):

[Shotwell](http://www.yorba.org/projects/shotwell/) is a simple and popular photo viewer and organizer for GNOME desktop and offers  features like rotate, crop, reduce red-eye etc.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I have shotwell for catalog. But it start longer then 10 gimps.

Answer (score 1):

If you're fine with using Wine then maybe give it a shot for IrfanView? I use it myself on my Linux VM. I've used [this instructions](http://www.boekhoff.info/?pid=linux&tip=install-irfan-view-on-linux).

Comment: I have a copy of installed Irfanview from a Windows machine and there is no problem to use it - works nice, just run the i_view32.exe. Ok, I do not use the context menu integration but for batch conversions etc. and quick editing it is fine.